# Windows xp install says hard disk is corrupted. It's not

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, usb, setup

I'm attempting to install Windows XP onto a netbook from a usb stick.

I get to the stage in the install where it asks if I want to format the drive to NFTS, I select yes, and it then fails.

An error message is displayed saying that the hard disk is corrupted and set up cannot continue.

The disk was working fine about a week ago, I don't see how this can be... Anyone know why this may be happening and how i can fix it?

I've tried booting GParted and removing the partition (it's just a single partition on the disk) and creating a new one again, but this hasn't changed anything.

Comment: When you create a new one, are you doing that in GParted or XP setup?

Comment: i've tried both, either way, when it gets to that part in xp setup i get that error

Comment: Try deleteing the partition in gparted and leaving the space unallocated. Then let XP create the partitions on install. If it still errors, you might need to find a tool to run diagnostics on the disk. Most drive manufacturers offer them on their tech support sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your manufacturer's website.  See if there is some sort of driver for the SATA drive.  Could be you have some sort of controller that XP doesn't have the proper driver for - you may need to install it during the setup.  That and/or look at your BIOS setup for what mode the controller is in - AHCI, RAID...  Set it to the most compatible mode and try again.

Comment: this was the problem :) Didn't think to check the BIOS for that - turns out the person whose laptop it is had given it to someone else to fix first. They must have changed that whilst not fixing it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you created your partition map as a GUID one which Windows XP don't support?

You should be able to see your partition map format with GParted. Make sure it's MBR format.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the XP installer to format the partition. In GParted, delete the current partition, create a new one *and format it to NTFS* using Linux tools.

If the format succeeds, XP will then install to this partition without insisting on formatting it.

If the Linux tools also report a disk problem, the problem is real and you should buy one (or get warranty replacement).